# Reading 31 bit Integer from Java InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, java-io

I'm trying to read a 31 bit long Integer from an InputStream in java and i can't figure a way out for doing this. I receive four byte from the InputStream and the first bit of the first byte is a reserved bit which is always unset (0x0) and the rest is 31 bit long integer.Here is a visualization of what i described :

```
+-+-------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
|R|                     31 bit long Integer                     |
+-+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me come up with a solution. Thanks!

Comment: When you say "the first bit of the first byte is a **reversed byte** which is always **onset** (0x0)", I think you meant to say "the first bit of the first byte is a **reserved bit** which is always **unset** (0x0)".

Comment: @Abra Since the "the first bit of the first byte" is where the `R` bit is, then it is big-endian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to read a 31 bit long Integer from an InputStream

That is impossible.

The minimum size of thing you can read is a byte, which is 8 bits; all things you can read from them are a multiple of 8.

> and the first bit of the first byte is a reversed byte which is always onset (0x0)

This sentence doesn't make any sense. The first 'bit of a byte' cannot be a 'reversed byte'. Given that bits are a 1-dimensional concept, there is no such thing as a 'reversed bit', and 'onset', if it means anything, means '1' and not '0', and bits are not as a rule communicated in '0x' syntax, which is hexadecimal.

I conclude you must be confused about the API.

However, to be a bit more helpful: If you have 4 bytes of data that contains a 31-bit-length integer, then:

1. You need to know if it is 'big endian' or 'little endian'. It will be someplace in the docs; usually protocols are big endian.
2. That first bit can trivially be stripped away or isolated, which should help.

Assuming big endian:

```
try (InputStream raw = socket.getInputStream();
     DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(raw)) {

  int v = data.readInt();
  boolean isolatedBit = (v >>> 31) != 0;
  v = v & 0x7FFFFFFF;
}
```

1. `DataInputStream` has the `readInt()` call that takes care of business.
2. `isolatedBit` will be 0 if that 'R' bit is unset, and '1' if it is iset.
3. Even if this R thing is set, that last line will ensure that the value of `v` has that bit unset. As a consequence, the number will be between 0 and 2^31-1 (thus, always positive).

---

NB: After some corrections to the original question, this is much simpler:

Given that the reserved bit is always unset, you can just call `int v = data.readInt()`, that's the only thing in the try block that would then be required. Had the 'reserved bit' always been a 1 - you *would* need that  `& 0x7FFFFFFF` to get rid of it.

Comment: I believe when OP said "the first bit of the first byte is a **reversed byte** which is always **onset** (0x0)", what OP meant to say was "the first bit of the first byte is a **reserved bit** which is always **unset** (0x0)"